# Oracle Apex - Bind variables on where statement

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have issues with my page 10, there's a interactive report with the following query:

```
select
id,
description,
status1,
status2,
status3
from My_table
where 
(status1 = :P10_status1 or :P10_status1 is null) 
and
(status2 = :P10_status2 or :P10_status2 is null) 
and
(status3 = :P10_status3 or :P10_status3 is null)
```

P10_status1, P10_status2 and P10_status3 come from page 5, one at a time, meaning...
If P10_status1 has a value then the other 2 do not, and so on.
Options for these items are:

```
 Y
 N
or no value ('')
```

DDL statements:

```
create table My_table
(
id number,
description varchar2(100),
status1 varchar2(100),
status2 varchar2(100),
status3 varchar2(100)
)

insert into My_table (id, description, status1, status2, status3)
values (1, 'Description1', 'Y', 'N', '')
insert into My_table (id, description, status1, status2, status3)
values (1, 'Description2', 'Y', 'Y', '')
insert into My_table (id, description, status1, status2, status3)
values (1, 'Description3', 'Y', '', '')
insert into My_table (id, description, status1, status2, status3)
values (1, 'Description4', 'N', '', '')
```

Query on my IR doesn't return all the values.
Anybody knows why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the cashing of the values of items.

If you are using Link Builder to create the link to page 10 then set the value of `Clear Cache` to 10.

[image]

If you create the URL manually then add in the URL `&clear=10` like this.

```
http://localhost:8080/ords/[WS_NAME]/r/[APP_NAME]/[PAGE_NAME]?p10_status2=Y&clear=10&session=2165310820583
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you meant to say by

> Query on my IR doesn't return all the values

but - to me - it looks as if you didn't set the "Page items to submit" property for that interactive report.

This:

[image]